# why the issuer name is reversed when i get it using python?

Tags: python, cryptography, ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate

i have a certificate and when i use python to get the issuer name of the certificate i get the issuer name reversed :

the correct issuer name : `CN=PEZEINVOICESCA2-CA,DC=extgazt,DC=gov,DC=local`

the issuer name that i get : `DC=local,DC=gov,DC=extgazt,CN=PEZEINVOICESCA2-CA`

this is the code that i use to get the issuer name :

```py
import cryptography.x509

your_Certificate = open("cert.txt","rb")
Certificate = your_Certificate.read().decode()
your_Certificate.close()


the_certificate = cryptography.x509.load_pem_x509_certificate("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n{}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----".format(Certificate).encode())
issuer_name = (str(the_certificate.issuer).split("(")[-1].split(")")[0])
print(issuer_name)
```

and this is the website that i get the correct issuer name from : `https://certlogik.com/`

this is my certificate :

> 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

i know that i can write it reversed agin but i want it comes correct from python itself.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43349987/order-of-subject-attributes-in-x509-certificate - what makes you say that the website is correct and python is wrong vs. it being the other way around!?

Comment: because i am working on an e invoicing project and when i send the invoice with the website's issuer name it been correct and they accept it , but when i use python they don't accept it and they say that my issuer name is wrong .... and the creator of the certificate sayes that python issuer name is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the desired order with [`rfc4514_string()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.Name.rfc4514_string), which returns the data according to [RFC 4514, sec. 2.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4514#section-2.1) (reverse order, comma separated):

```py
print(the_certificate.issuer.rfc4514_string())
```

gives

```
CN=PEZEINVOICESCA2-CA,DC=extgazt,DC=gov,DC=local
```